# Tensorflow couldn't open CUDA library libcupti.so.8.0 during training on google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying train a model using Tensorflow on the Google Cloud ml-engine. It seems that tensorflow can't get to the libcupti files on the cloud compute machine due to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH not pointing to the correct directory, as implied by the log entry below:

```
lineno: 126    
  message: "Couldn't open CUDA library libcupti.so.8.0.
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64"    
levelname: "INFO"    
pathname: "tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc"    
created: 1491143889.84344
```

As far as I know, the libcupti files are all in `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64`, so I would need to append this to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but how would I do that when submitting a job via a `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME` command? Or maybe there's an easier solution?

Comment: Would this error be triggered for all GPU training jobs? Are you able to run any training jobs on GPUs with Google Cloud?

Comment: I haven't had time yet to try to test another type of job... I'll try that though if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use GPU with tensorflow on google cloud and it works for me. In my code I didn't do any GPU specific setting (nor set anything with LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

I think you can try with just a simple and standard tensorflow code and with you submit the job you attach a config then the job should automatically use GPU to do the calculation for you.

Try add a file such as `cloudml-gpu.yaml` in your module with the following content:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 
GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.0"
```

Then add a option called `--config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml` (suppose your training module is in a folder called `trainer`). For example:

```
export BUCKET_NAME=tf-learn-simple-sentiment
export JOB_NAME="example_5_train_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
export JOB_DIR=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
export REGION=europe-west1

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --job-dir gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME \
  --runtime-version 1.0 \
  --module-name trainer.example5-keras \
  --package-path ./trainer \
  --region $REGION \
  --config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml \
  -- \
  --train-file gs://tf-learn-simple-sentiment/sentiment_set.pickle
```